# Confused by definition of stationary stochastic process

Tags: stochastic-processes, stationarity

Borrowing heavily from definition of stationary stochastic process [here](https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/varadhan/course/PROB.ch6.pdf), I am having a hard time understanding why

$$F(X_{n_1}, X_{n_2},...,X_{n_k}) = F(X_{n_1+n},...,X_{n_k+n}),$$

for every $k \ge 1$, and $n, n_1,...n_k \in \mathbb{Z}$  where $F$ is the joint distribution, does not simply imply that (or, if it does, why it is not stated as such) $X_{n}$ is the same for every $n$

Thanks

Comment: Joint distribution is more informative than each marginal distribution of the components of the joint distribution. Marginal distribution being the same for every $n$ is less restrictive than joint distribution being the same when shifted across time.

Comment: Actually this definition implies, that $X_n$ *has the same distribution* for each $n$. But this does not mean that $X_n$ are the same. Take for example standard normal variable $Z$. Then $Z$ and $-Z$ have the same distribution (because of the symmetry), but clearly they are not the same.

Comment: @mpiktas, also, you say 'this definition'. Is this not the standard definition?

Comment: Yes, this definition is a standard for strictly stationary processes. Although usualy $t_k$ are used instead of $n_k$.